# Group and sum duplicate elements in a for loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a for loop like so:

```
for((int) $i = 0; $i < $number_of_updates; $i++) 
{

        //query here
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $points = 1;

        //some functions to execute here... and then

        //store results in session to show on other page
        $output = $points.' times '.$name;
        $_SESSION['item'][] = $output;

}
```

And then I show my results on view page like so:

```
foreach (array_unique($_SESSION['item']) as $output) 
{
    echo ('<p>'.$output.'</p>'); 
}
```

It echoes my results out of the loop like so:

1 times foo

1 times foo

1 times bar

1 times foo

etc...

**Now the question.** How do I sum those results up so they don't duplicate? Instead they are shown like so:

3 times foo

1 times bar

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `array_count_values`

```
for(/*(int) <- this is not neccessary (c++ background?) */ $i = 0; $i < $number_of_updates; $i++) 
{
    // your code
    $_SESSION['item'][] = $name;

}

foreach(array_count_values($_SESSION['item']) as $name => $times)
    echo ('<p>'.$times.' times '.$name.'</p>');
```

Of course counting the values directly is more memory and time efficient. This version is only neccessary if you somehow need to preserve the order of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you store in your array directly the sum?

```
for((int) $i = 0; $i < $number_of_updates; $i++) 
{

    //query here
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $points = 1;

    //some functions to execute here... and then

    //store results in session to show on other page
    $_SESSION['item'][$name] +=$points;
}
```

Comment: You can echo $_SESSION['item']: `foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $name=>$times) { echo ("<p>$times times $name</p>"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for((int) $i = 0; $i < $number_of_updates; $i++) 
{

        //query here
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $points = 1;

        //some functions to execute here... and then

        //store results in session to show on other page
        //$output = $points.' times '.$name;
        //$_SESSION['item'][] = $output;

        if( isset( $_SESSION['count'][$name]  )){
            $prev   = $_SESSION['count'][$name];
        }else{
            $prev   = 0;    
        }

        $_SESSION['count'][$name] = $points + $prev ;
}

print_r( $_SESSION['count'] );
```